# eclipse add own Project Configuration UI Elements

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Hy i wrote a eclipse plugin that generates some stuff for cdt using xtext.
Now i would like to add a Configuration UI to the Projects.

Can some one tellme where i find a example of how to extend the Project Property Window?

Comment: In the Eclipse help [contributing a property page](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fpreferences_prop_contribute.htm)

Comment: Thanks Some Times you look on the wrong places ^^.